# Python customization of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

I have a Pascal's triangle (first 2 elements excluded) and custom triangle as such:

```
 P=[[1, 2, 1],
 [1, 3, 3, 1],
 [1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
 [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1],
 [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]]
```

The second Pascal is:

```
 P2=[[2],
 [2, 2],
 [2, 4, 2],
 [2, 6, 6, 2],
 [2, 8, 12, 8, 2],
 [2, 10, 20, 20, 10, 2]]
```

But I want to generate a new custom Pascal's triangle as such formula:

```
-get P[0][1]
-add it to P2[0]
-write again P[0][1] as 4.

-get P[1][1]
-add it to P2[0]
-add it to P[0][0:2]
-write again P[1][1] as 7.
```

the last scenario will be recursive then.

Here is the result:

```
 newpascal=[[1, 4, 1],
 [1, 7, 7, 1],
 [1, 10, 18, 10, 1],
 [1, 13, 34, 34, 13, 1],
 [1, 16, 55, 80, 55, 16, 1]]
```

My code doesn't work:

```
#Definition of classical Pascal's Triangle   
def pascal1(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [[1]]
    else:
        final_r = pascal1(n - 1)
        last = [0] + final_r[-1] + [0] # note: this does not modify final_r
        new_row = [last[k] + last[k - 1] for k in range(1, len(last))]
        return final_r + [new_row]
p=pascal1(10)

#Definition of Pascal's Triangle (Times2X)
def pascal2(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [[2]]
    else:
        final_r = pascal2(n - 1)
        last = [0] + final_r[-1] + [0] # note: this does not modify final_r
        new_row = [last[k] + last[k - 1] for k in range(1, len(last))]
        return final_r + [new_row]
p2=pascal2(10)


#My Custom Pascal
def newpascal(n):
    final_r = pascal1(n - 1)
    last = [0] + final_r[-1] + [0] # note: this does not modify final_r
    new_row = [last[k] + last[k - 1]+p2[0][0] for k in range(1, len(last))]
    return final_r + [new_row]
```

Comment: What exactly does not work in your code? What do you get?

Comment: newpascal result in as such: [[1],
 [1, 1],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [1, 3, 3, 1],
 [1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
 [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1],
 [1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1],
 [1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1],
 [1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1],
 [1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1],
 [3, 12, 47, 122, 212, 254, 212, 122, 47, 12, 3]]

Comment: I do not understand the definition of your custom Pascal triangle. Why is `[1 4 1]` followed by `[1 7 7 1]`?

Comment: There are two pascals. I am mixing two of them by using my formula stated above and then generating a new custom pascal's triangle. in order to generate it, i should use these two ones, the original and the increasing one. here is brief calculation: (1+4) and get first element of P2[1] as 2. that is the first 7. after that (4+1) and get second element of P2[1], it is again 7. [1 7 7 1] must be followed by [1 10 18 10 1]. Get (1+7) and add first element of P2[2] , it is 10; get (7+7) and add second element of P2[2], it is ( 7+7+4). i know it is more complicated but i solved a great pattern.

Comment: isn't there anyone to look at the code or logic behind?

Comment: What is the expected output for new pascal?

Answer (score 0):

I worked through your nearly indecipherable instructions and came up with the following:

```
def newpascal(n):
    array = pascal1(1)[1]
    p2 = pascal2(n)
    p3 = [list(array)]

    for x, row in enumerate(range(3, n + 2), start=0):

        array.append(1) # both widen the row and initialize last element

        # fill in the row, right to left
        for y, i in enumerate(range(row - 2, 0, -1)):
            # current computed from previous + p2
            array[i] += array[i - 1] + p2[x][y]

        p3.append(list(array))

    return p3
```

Unfortunately, it's not recursive.  But it seems to work:

```
>>> p3 = newpascal(10)
>>> print(*p3, sep='\n')
[1, 1]
[1, 4, 1]
[1, 7, 7, 1]
[1, 10, 18, 10, 1]
[1, 13, 34, 34, 13, 1]
[1, 16, 55, 80, 55, 16, 1]
[1, 19, 81, 155, 155, 81, 19, 1]
[1, 22, 112, 266, 350, 266, 112, 22, 1]
[1, 25, 148, 420, 686, 686, 420, 148, 25, 1]
[1, 28, 189, 624, 1218, 1512, 1218, 624, 189, 28, 1]
>>>
```

In your explanation, `pascal1()` is a red herring as it's not needed to solve this problem.  You just need to start with `[[1, 1]]`.  So now it's time to clue us in on the "great pattern" you solved!

Comment: i am really sorry for my message. your comments were appreciated. since the problem is a bit hard, i may not clearly explain it. i generated the solution, yours one is also working, great job!